# Was the Original SQL Written in Assembly or C?

Tags: sql, assembly

I know that vendors have their own subset of the Original SQL Language that are written in C (Like for Postgre SQL) or MS-SQL Server (C++) etc....

So, was the original SQL written in C, or was it created itself in Assembly? I couldn't really find a definite answer on what it's original language roots are (besides the history and such)

Comment: I doubt it was written in assembly.

Comment: How a language can be written using another language ? You think that SQL is like a subset of C ?

Comment: I think he is referring to the original interpreter.  Although in the early 70s, it might have been something like fortran or cobol.

Comment: Yes I meant the interpreter, and most places seem to say C for the first 'Commercial' Database, but I cannot find anywhere that says what this original language's interpreter was written in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick [history](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_edb_pl_sql_features_release.htm) search on Oracle yielded:

> In the late 70s, around the time Ingres was getting started at UC Berkeley, three guys working on a contract for the CIA got together and started a company called Relational Software, Inc.
>
> Their first product was a relational database called Oracle.  The
>   founders decided to use the C language for development.  This would
>   later become important when they decided to start porting to different
>   platforms.
>
> They also decided to support SQL as the internal data access language.
>   This would also become a very important factor to its success.  In
>   1979, Relational Software was the only company making an SQL compliant
>   database.  If anyone ever asks you who wrote the first SQL database,
>   you now know the answer: Oracle.

So the answer is C - according to Burleson Consulting.

Comment: Since SQL was originally written by IBM as part of [System R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_R), quoting what Oracle used to implement their variant of SQL is not entirely relevant.  IBM used PL/I in the first implementation of SQL.

Answer (score 5):

[PL/I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I).

From [A History and Evaluation 
of System R](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262/SystemR.pdf):

> An interpreter program was written in PL/I to execute statements 
>   in the high-level SQL (formerly 
>   SEQUEL) language on top 
>   of XRM.

The prototype for [System R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_R) was developed in 1974-75.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-databases.htm

> 1979 - Version 2.0 of Oracle was released and it became first commercial relational database and first SQL database. The company changed its name to Relational Software Inc. (RSI).
>
> 1983 - Oracle released version 3.0, rewritten in C language and ran on multiple platforms.