# SQL: source code / under the hood

Tags: sql

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of SQL, and I was just wondering - what was SQL originally written in? I did some research, and according to [this stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020999/was-the-original-sql-written-in-assembly-or-c), it seems that SQL was originally written in C. If so, is there any way I could access the original source code to see how SQL *really* works under the hood - its algorithms, data structures etc? If SQL was indeed written in C, its inner workings must be imperative since C is an imperative language, and since I am more versed in C++ than in SQL, it would be really rewarding to explore SQL in terms of an imperative paradigm. Thanks in advance for any insight you may have!

Comment: SQL is a language. As pointed out in the linked question, do you mean the original interpreter? If you want more information about the language specification, I'd start at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I'm not sure that the original SQL was written in C, though many of the early workalikes certainly were.  The original (SEQUEL for [System R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_R)) was written by IBM, and was written PL/I.  What you're asking for, though, is very close to a software recommendation, and that isn't really on-topic for SO.

Comment: Incidentally, the accepted answer on the cross-referenced question ([Was the original SQL written in assembly or C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020999/was-the-original-sql-written-in-assembly-or-c) is simply wrong.  The correct answer is PL/I.  You can look at the article referenced from the [System R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System_R) page on Wikipedia and see that it says that it was written in PL/I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is a language *definition*, which itself is not written in anything but plain text.

Also, you can implement a compiler/engine for SQL or Java or whatever high level language in C++, C, Assembly, or even directly in machine code if you like, so the language in which it is implemented doesn't tell you anything about its possibilities.

Comment: Just out of interest, how may I go about writing my own SQL compiler in C++?

Answer (score 1):

Which SQL? There are a *lot* of different competing SQL database flavors out there: Sql Server, Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL, Access, SqlLite, Sybase... and that's just the tip of the iceberg. Fortunately, [several](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/guided-tour.html) of [those](https://github.com/postgres/postgres) are [open source](http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md)... you can go look at the code for yourself.

You can also read the [Sql Language Specifications.](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/search.htm?qt=9075&sort=rel&type=simple&published=on)